# Is Yahari Ore no Seishun Love Comedy wa Machigatteiru. Light novel concluded?

Tags: oregairu

I could only find until volume 12 and I read somewhere that volume 13 and 14 will be the conclusion. I would like to know if it's already released. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Gagaga Bunko, the publisher of *Oregairu* light novel made [a tweet on 28 Sept 2017 (Japanese)](https://twitter.com/gagaga_bunko/status/913319919873228801):

> 【俺ガイル１２】ちなみに、先日のイベントのステージにサプライズ出演された渡航先生より「俺ガイル12巻は終章の上、中、下巻の上巻に当たる」「中、下巻にあたる13巻と14巻は同時くらいに発売」との発表があり、現在制作進行です！！お楽しみに！！！！！（☆）

To put it simply, volume 12 is the 1st part of the 3-part final chapter, and volume 13 & 14 ―the 2nd and 3rd part― will be published almost at the same time.

However, as of current writing, volumes 13 & 14 haven't been published.